# Egrep back referencing not working

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have trying top back reference the first captured group in the below command:

```
$ ls -lR | egrep 'd(rw(x|s)|rw-|r-(x|s)|-w(x|s)|r--|-w-|--(x|s))(rw(x|s)|rw-|r-(x|s)|-w(x|s)|r--|-w-|--(x|s))---'
drwxr-s--- 2 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:53 dir1
dr-xrws--- 2 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:53 dir2
dr-xrws--- 2 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:53 dir3
drwxrws--- 2 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:53 dir4
drwxrws--- 4 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:55 subdir
drwxrws--- 2 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:54 dir5
drwxrws--- 2 s9akhtar s9akhtar 4096 Feb 25 11:54 dir6
```

So I want to do something like this :

```
 ls -lR | egrep "d(rw(x|s)|rw-|r-(x|s)|-w(x|s)|r--|-w-|--(x|s))\1---"
```

but it comes up empty

How come the back reference of the first captured group the big bracket not working:

```
(rw(x|s)|rw-|r-(x|s)|-w(x|s)|r--|-w-|--(x|s))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are actually trying to match. Simply showing a relatively complex regex and saying it doesn't work is pointless unless you also explain what you were expecting it to do. You should also probably have a look at [why parsing ls is a bad idea](mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you are trying to get directories with specific permissions there are much easier and safer ways than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *repeat the pattern* you need to use a count suffix of `{2}` instead of `\1`, which instead repeats *the string the first pattern matched*. Try:

```
egrep '^d(rw(x|s)|rw-|r-(x|s)|-w(x|s)|r--|-w-|--(x|s)){2}---'
```

which you can simplify to:

```
egrep '^d(r[w-][xs-]|-w[xs-]|--[xs]){2}---'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is an impenetrable regex. I hope it's well documented for the next poor sap who has to maintain it.

You might want to do stuff with the numeric permissions instead:

```
find . -type d -printf "%m %p\n" | filter somehow based on the permissions
```